# I am using ordertable for server side response.Html tag double quotes are mismatched in jsonencode response

Tags: php, html, quoting

I am sending data from controller using json_encode():

```
$status =     "<td id=status_".$value['id'].">".
                  "<button class='btn btn-icon-toggle active'  href='javascript:;' onclick='changeStatus(".$value['id'].", '0', ".$field.", ".$url.",".$action.")><i class='fa fa-check'></i>
                   </button> </td>";
```

The Output are:

```
<button class="btn btn-icon-toggle active" href="javascript:;" onclick="changeStatus(1510, " 0',="" status,="" stores="" ajaxaction,restaurantstatus)="">
```

I need output is:

```
<button class="btn btn-icon-toggle active" href="javascript:;" onclick="changeStatus(1510,0,'status','stores/ajaxaction','restaurantstatus')">
```

what will I do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just learn the [string escape characters](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/2/6/2/escape-sequences) and play with it!

```
$status = "<td id=\"status_".$value['id']."\">" . "<button class=\"btn btn-icon-toggle active\"  href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"changeStatus(".$value['id'].", 0, '".$field."', '".$url."','".$action."')\"><i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i> </button> </td>";
```